Symfony serializer not serializing all class fields
I have two classes, one is for managing Events and the other are the Users. Users can participate to Events. When they participate they become "Attendees".
The issue is when I serialize an event with attendees, the response contains all field except the attendees field.
The Event class:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\CustomIdGenerator;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToMany;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToOne;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Timestampable;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation\Uploadable;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation\UploadableField;

#[Entity]
#[Table(name: 'event')]
#[Uploadable]
class Event
{
    #[Id]
    #[GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[CustomIdGenerator(class: UUIDGenerator::class)]
    #[Column]
    #[Groups(['apiExposed'])]
    private string $id;

    #[Column]
    #[Groups(['apiExposed', 'searchable'])]
    #[NotBlank]
    private string $title;

    #[Column(type: 'point', nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['apiExposed', 'searchable'])]
    private ?Point $location;

    #[ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class)]
    #[Groups('apiExposed')]
    #[NotBlank]
    private User $organizer;

    #[ManyToMany(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'participatedEvents')]
    #[Groups('apiExposed')]
    private Collection $attendees;

    #[Column(type: 'text')]
    #[Groups(['apiExposed', 'searchable'])]
    #[NotBlank]
    private string $description;

    #[Column]
    #[Groups(['aîExposed', 'searchable'])]
    #[NotBlank]
    private string $address;

    #[UploadableField(mapping: 'event_picture', fileNameProperty: 'pictureName')]
    private ?File $pictureFile = null;

    #[Column(nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['apiExposed', 'searchable'])]
    private ?string $pictureName = 'event.jpg';

    #[Column]
    #[Groups(['apiExposed', 'searchable'])]
    private bool $isSecret = false;

    #[Column]
    #[Groups(['apiExposed', 'searchable'])]
    private \DateTimeImmutable $startDate;

    #[Column]
    #[Groups('apiExposed')]
    #[Timestampable(on: 'create')]
    private \DateTimeImmutable $createdAt;

    #[Column]
    #[Groups('apiExposed')]
    #[Timestampable(on: 'update')]
    private \DateTimeImmutable $updatedAt;

    // Getters and setters
    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
     public function getAttendees(): Collection
     {
         return $this->attendees;
     }

     /**
      * @param User $user
      * @return $this
      */
     public function addAttendee(User $user): Event
     {
         $this -> attendees -> add($user);
         return $this;
     }

     /**
      * @param User $user
      * @return $this
      */
     public function removeAttendee(User $user): Event
     {
         $this -> attendees -> removeElement($user);
         return $this;
      }

}

The User class:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Timestampable;
use OpenApi\Attributes\Items;
use OpenApi\Attributes\Property;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation\Uploadable;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation\UploadableField;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`user`')]
#[Uploadable]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups('apiExposed')]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 180, unique: true)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Groups('apiExposed')]
    private ?string $username = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups('apiExposed')]
    #[Property(type: 'array', items: new Items(type: 'string'))]
    private array $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     */
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    private ?string $password = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    #[Groups('apiExposed')]
    private ?string $bio = null;

    #[ORM\Column(unique: true)]
    #[Assert\Email]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Groups('apiExposed')]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[UploadableField(mapping: 'user_picture', fileNameProperty: 'pictureName')]
    private ?File $pictureFile = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    #[Groups('apiExposed')]
    private ?string $pictureName = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Car::class, mappedBy: 'user')]
    private Collection $cars;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Event::class, mappedBy: 'attendees')]
    private Collection $participatedEvents;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Timestampable(on: 'create')]
    #[Groups('apiExposed')]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $createdAt;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Timestampable(on: 'update')]
    #[Groups('apiExposed')]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $updatedAt;

    // Getters and setters

}

The method where the Event is serialized:
#[OA\Response(response: 200, description: 'Returns an event given by its ID.', content: new Model(type: Event::class, groups: ['apiExposed']))]
    #[OA\Response(response: 404, description: 'No event found with this ID.')]
    #[OA\Response(response: 403, description: 'Event is secret for the current user.')]
    #[OA\Tag(name: 'Event')]
    public function getByID(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
                            SerializerInterface $serializer,
                            string $eventId): JsonResponse
    {
        //getting event
        $event = $entityManager -> getRepository(Event::class) -> find($eventId);

        //checking if exists
        if (!$event) {
            return new JsonResponse([
                'code' => Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND,
                'error' => 'Unknown event'
            ], Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }

        //check if event is secret
        if ($event -> isSecret() && $event -> getOrganizer() != $this -> getUser()) {
            return new JsonResponse([
                'code' => Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN,
                'error' => 'Event is secret'
            ], Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
        }

        return JsonResponse::fromJsonString($serializer -> serialize($event, 'json', ['groups' => 'apiExposed']));
    }

I maybe miss something using ManyToMany relationship and serializer but I don't guess where.
Thanks

Can you please show as well your getter for the attendees property ? If it exists, have you tried to define the #[Groups('apiExposed')] on it ?

I edited the original question with the getters and settes for the attendees property. Yes the serializer group is already defined on it.

Is your DB filled with correct datas ? tables event, user and event_user with correct ids. I tried your code and it's working here, could you maybe add the part where you call the Serializer ?

Yes when I add an attendee, the correct IDs are stored in the event_user table. I add the part where I call the serializer in the question.

I think this may have to do with collections being lazy-loaded by default, try fetching the  collection before serializing i.e. call $event->getAttendees()

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#skipping-uninitialized-properties , I know if you dump the entity the collection fields will show as empty/uninitialized if you have not accessed the field prior.

When dumping the $event var, the attendees collection is showed and initialized. Calling $event -> getAttendees() before serializing does nothing.

For me it actually helped calling collection getter. Regarding link - https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#skipping-uninitialized-properties - I was not gettign error, only the field was not appearing.
But I do not get - how to correctly fix this. Because now calling collection and not using its return value makes code looking weird, IDE gives warning.

But it worked only on minimal setup, on full code - did not work.

Using the JMSSerializerBundle seems working fine with this relationship. Maybe JMS supports ManyToMany relations better than the Symfony serializer do.
